# Using a function to output the character value of the input

Tags: r

How do I tell a function to output the name of the input?

For example:

```
test <- function (thisisthename) {
print (thisisthename)
}

input <- apple
```

Now if I do:

```
test(input)
```

it will output

```
"apple"
```

but how do I make it output "input," as "input" is the name of the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
test <- function (thisisthename) {
    substitute(thisisthename)
}
```

or use `deparse(substitute(thisisthename))` if you need it with quotes.

Comment: No, I only saw it after posting mine. Good answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `substitute(x)` returns the parse tree (the internal representation of the argument x) to which the variable `x` refers, and `deparese` takes a parse tree and returns a string with an R code representation of that parse tree. Hence, `FUN` returns a string representation of the argument `x`:

```
FUN = function(x)deparse(substitute(x))
```

Just remember that `deparse` does the opposite of parsing - which is taking code and generating the symbolic tree that R can evaluate.  Hence, `FUN` returns the expression, which can be the variable name as in:

```
FUN(x=foo)
#> "foo"
```

or an expression:

```
FUN(x=1:2 + 3)
#> 1:2 + 3
```

Note that deparsing does not exactly recapitulate the code text that was entered:

```
FUN(x=1:2+3)
#> 1:2 + 3
FUN(x=1:2      +       3)
#> 1:2 + 3
```

and that `deparse(substitute(x))` works for ordinary variables, not just function arguments:

```
y = 1:2 + 3
deparse(substitute(y))
#> 1:2 + 3
```

Comment: could use explanation

Comment: Added an explanaintion - better a little late than a little never...